# pls help me fix it. I need a way that I have to use an else to press a button that will move me to another form

Tags: vb.net

I need a way that I have to use an else to press a button that will move me to another form (Sorry for my bad English ^-^)

```
    Else
    Form3.Show()
    Me.Hide()
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an `Exit Sub` directly above an `End Sub`.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If 1 <> 1 Then
        'never True
    Else
        Me.Hide()
        Form3.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: ty You've been very helpful! And another question how to allow access to specific characters in the textbox I want?

Comment: @Ofir You will need to ask another question.